# Is SSMS refresh speed a latency or performance indicator?

Tags: ssms

Via SSMS, I connected to both SQL Server instances. One is the Azure SQL Database, and the other is a Windows shared host.

In the Azure instance, I go to *Tables* and click on *Refresh*. It consistently takes over 4 seconds for the tables to fnally show up.

On the other hand, this consistently takes less than 2 seconds in my other Windows shared host.

I may be overthinking this, but why would it take so much longer with the Azure instance?

[image]